# Vista network only local access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista

I have just restored a windows vista laptop. Now it cannot access the internet using wifi connection.
The laptop connects to the router and i assigned an IP number. My windows 7 pc can access the internet using wifi. I have tried to compare the result of ipconfig /all
And and default gateway and dhcp server is the same. However if i ping the router (192.168.1.**1**)

Im getting response from 192.168.1.**8** is not accessible 192.168.1.8 is the ip of the laptop

I have installed sp1 and sp2.

I have tried http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928233/en-us

Comment: Can you post the ipconfig readout of both computers? You might also try 'ipconfig /release' followed by 'ipconfig /renew' in a cmd window that has Run as Administrator rights. Also restarting the router and the computer to clear caches might not be a bad idea.

Comment: 1.) can you ping 127.0.0.1 ? 2.) Check your subnet mask and gateway address again. 3.)What wifi sec are you using? please update this in the your question.